# CartoDB Infowindow createLayer with Layersource

Tags: carto, carto-js, infowindow

I replicated an example of a layer with customized infowindows, but when I changed the source to a layer source object, the layers are loaded but the infowindow fails to show up. Any pointers.. http://bl.ocks.org/jmwenda/be0d7468fd4f8c17fcf30b51975031d1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Custom infowindow example | CartoDB.js</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartodb.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
  <span> custom </span>
  <div class="cartodb-popup">
    <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>

     <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
       <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
         <img style="width: 100%" src="http://rambo.webcindario.com/images/18447755.jpg">
         <!-- content.data contains the field info -->
         <h4>{{content.data.name}}</h4>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
  </div>
</script>

<script src="http://libs.cartodb.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

<script>
  function main() {
    var map = L.map('map', {
      zoomControl: false,
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 3
    });

    // add a nice baselayer from Stamen
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Stamen'
    }).addTo(map);

    var markersLayerSource = {

    }

    cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: 'nation',
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [
        {
          sql: "WITH hgridA AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 48), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 48) as cell), bigs AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridA, (select * from reports WHERE published = true) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridA.cell) GROUP BY hgridA.cell) t WHERE points_count > 100 ), hgridB AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 36), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 36) as cell), mids AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridB, (select * from reports WHERE published = true) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridB.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) GROUP BY hgridB.cell) t WHERE points_count > 25 ), hgridC AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24) as cell), smalls AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridC, (select * from reports WHERE published = true) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridC.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM mids) GROUP BY hgridC.cell) t WHERE points_count > 5 ) SELECT the_geom_webmercator, 1 points_count, cartodb_id, ARRAY[cartodb_id] as id_list, 'origin' as src, cartodb_id::text cdb_list FROM reports WHERE published = true AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM mids) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM smalls) UNION ALL SELECT *, 'bigs' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM bigs UNION ALL SELECT *, 'mids' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM mids UNION ALL SELECT *, 'smalls' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM smalls",
          https: 'force https',
          cartocss: "#reports {marker-width: 12;marker-fill: #109DCD;marker-opacity: 0.6;marker-line-width: 0;marker-allow-overlap: true;marker-comp-op: dst-atop;[src = 'smalls'] {marker-width: 20; }[src = 'mids'] {marker-width: 44;}[src = 'bigs'] { marker-width: 64; }[zoom>11]{marker-width: 52;}}#reports::lables {text-size: 0;text-fill: black;text-opacity: 0.8;text-name: [points_count];text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';text-halo-fill: #fff;text-halo-radius: 0;[src = 'smalls'] {text-size: 18; text-halo-radius: 1; }[src = 'mids'] {text-size: 26; text-halo-radius: 1; }[src = 'bigs'] { text-size: 32; text-halo-radius: 1; } text-allow-overlap: true;[zoom>11] {text-size: 36;}}",
          interactivity: 'cartodb_id, cdb_list',
        },{
          sql: "WITH hgridA AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 48), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 48) as cell), bigs AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridA, (select * from reports WHERE verified = true and published = false) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridA.cell) GROUP BY hgridA.cell) t WHERE points_count > 100 ), hgridB AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 36), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 36) as cell), mids AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridB, (select * from reports WHERE verified = true and published = false) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridB.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) GROUP BY hgridB.cell) t WHERE points_count > 25 ), hgridC AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24) as cell), smalls AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridC, (select * from reports WHERE verified = true and published = false) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridC.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM mids) GROUP BY hgridC.cell) t WHERE points_count > 5 ) SELECT the_geom_webmercator, 1 points_count, cartodb_id, ARRAY[cartodb_id] as id_list, 'origin' as src, cartodb_id::text cdb_list FROM reports WHERE verified = true AND published = false AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM mids) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM smalls) UNION ALL SELECT *, 'bigs' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM bigs UNION ALL SELECT *, 'mids' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM mids UNION ALL SELECT *, 'smalls' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM smalls",
          https: 'force https',
          cartocss: "#reports {marker-width: 12;marker-fill: #99FF00;marker-opacity: 0.6;marker-line-width: 0;marker-allow-overlap: true;marker-comp-op: dst-atop;[src = 'smalls'] {marker-width: 20; }[src = 'mids'] {marker-width: 44;}[src = 'bigs'] { marker-width: 64; }[zoom>11]{marker-width: 52;}}#reports::lables {text-size: 0;text-fill: black;text-opacity: 0.8;text-name: [points_count];text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';text-halo-fill: #fff;text-halo-radius: 0;[src = 'smalls'] {text-size: 18; text-halo-radius: 1; }[src = 'mids'] {text-size: 26; text-halo-radius: 1; }[src = 'bigs'] { text-size: 32; text-halo-radius: 1; } text-allow-overlap: true;[zoom>11] {text-size: 36;}}",
          interactivity: 'cartodb_id, cdb_list',
        },{
          sql: "WITH hgridA AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 48), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 48) as cell),bigs AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridA, (select * from reports WHERE verified = false and published = false) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridA.cell) GROUP BY hgridA.cell) t WHERE points_count > 100 ), hgridB AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 36), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 36) as cell), mids AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridB, (select * from reports WHERE verified = false and published = false) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridB.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) GROUP BY hgridB.cell) t WHERE points_count > 25 ), hgridC AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 24) as cell), smalls AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(i.the_geom_webmercator)) as the_geom_webmercator, count(i.cartodb_id) as points_count, 1 as cartodb_id, array_agg(cartodb_id) AS id_list FROM hgridC, (select * from reports WHERE verified = false and published = false) i where ST_Intersects(i.the_geom_webmercator, hgridC.cell) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(id_list) FROM mids) GROUP BY hgridC.cell) t WHERE points_count > 5 ) SELECT the_geom_webmercator, 1 points_count, cartodb_id, ARRAY[cartodb_id] as id_list, 'origin' as src, cartodb_id::text cdb_list FROM reports WHERE verified = false AND published = false AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM bigs) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM mids) AND cartodb_id NOT IN (select unnest(id_list) FROM smalls) UNION ALL SELECT *, 'bigs' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM bigs UNION ALL SELECT *, 'mids' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM mids UNION ALL SELECT *, 'smalls' as src, array_to_string(id_list, ',') FROM smalls",
          https: 'force https',
          cartocss: "#reports {marker-width: 12;marker-fill: #8b0000;marker-opacity: 0.6;marker-line-width: 0;marker-allow-overlap: true;marker-comp-op: dst-atop;[src = 'smalls'] {marker-width: 20; }[src = 'mids'] {marker-width: 44;}[src = 'bigs'] { marker-width: 64; }[zoom>11]{marker-width: 52;}}#reports::lables {text-size: 0;text-fill: black;text-opacity: 0.8;text-name: [points_count];text-face-name: 'DejaVu Sans Book';text-halo-fill: #fff;text-halo-radius: 0;[src = 'smalls'] {text-size: 18; text-halo-radius: 1; }[src = 'mids'] {text-size: 26; text-halo-radius: 1; }[src = 'bigs'] { text-size: 32; text-halo-radius: 1; } text-allow-overlap: true;[zoom>11] {text-size: 36;}}",
          interactivity: 'cartodb_id, cdb_list',
        }]
      })
     .addTo(map)
     .on('done', function(layer) {
       // get sublayer 0 and set the infowindow template
       var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
       console.log(sublayer);

       sublayer.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
      }).on('error', function() {
        console.log("some error occurred");
      });
  }

  window.onload = main;
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you have missed the interactivity columns parameter in the infowindow creation. I would do it like this.

```
.on('done', function(layer) {
       var sublayer0 = layer.getSubLayer(0);
       cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, sublayer0, 
          ['cartodb_id', 'name', 'description'],
          {infowindowTemplate: $('#infowindow_template').html()});
```

Bear in mind that you would need a different infowindow for each sublayer. Check [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/93c9c083f3b0897c5c75) to see how to add a different infowindow to each sublayer in a visualization.

Comment: Hey thanks, I have it as follows now. http://bl.ocks.org/jmwenda/b472b0a932fc5b895a5e59dadac18192. Do you have any pointers on how I could have the infowindow automatically close on featureOut? Rather than having to physically close the infowindow on hover?

Comment: You may want to add a Hover Tooltip instead of an Infowindow.
The Hover Tooltip will open and close automatically with featureOver and featureOut events. 
Check this example: http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/b99e617a71a39e2f140f