# Infowindow close on featureOut /hoverOut

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js, infowindow

I have been working on getting infowindows on my cartodb layers, but i am not sure what I am doing wrong as I want the infowindows to automatically close on feature out and only pop up when featurein or on hover regardless of the sublayer. A simple scaled down approach is as shown here. http://bl.ocks.org/jmwenda/b472b0a932fc5b895a5e59dadac18192. I have tried other methods such as shown with very little success. Any pointers on what I going on here or how to trigger the infowindow to automatically close?

```
  cartodb.createLayer(map, markersLayerSource)
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layer) {
             var publishedLayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
             publishedLayer.setInteraction(true);
             var infowindow = publishedLayer.infowindow;
             cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, publishedLayer,['cartodb_id','cdb_list'],{triggerEvent: 'featureOver'});

             publishedLayer.on('featureOver', function (e, latlng, pos, data, layer) {
                      //$(document).bind('mousemove', event);
                      $('.cartodb-popup').show();
                      //infowindow.set('visibility', true);

             });

             publishedLayer.on('featureOut', function (e, latlng, pos, data, layer) {
                      $('.cartodb-popup').hide();
                      //$(document).unbind('mousemove', event, false);
                      //infowindow.set('visibility', false);
             });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attaching the tooltips to every sublayer, you can create two (or many) layers with `createLayer` and then append the tooltips (an infowindow which shows when hovers over and hide when hovers out any layer feature, as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208812/cartodb-infowindow-createlayer-with-layersource#comment317931_208864)) to these layers:

1. First, set your `markerLayerSource` with your proper `query` and
   `style` for each layer.
2. Secondly, use `createLayer` with these parameters. [Remember](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208864/41250) to set the interaction (of the layer) and the interactivity (of the fields).
3. Create a variable called `tooltip` with Leaflet's `layer.leafletMap.viz.addOverlay` method and append it with jQuery to the `<body>`.

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/567c41b317f06b7bf31341f2ab7c1dc8) you have a working example.